# Use generic collections

Tags: java, generics, collections, arraylist

It's compiles and **run** successfully!

```
List a=new ArrayList<String>();
a.add(new Integer(5));
```

Can anybody explain this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reason is that you are declaring variable `a` to be a raw list i.e. `List` without any associated type:

```
List a = new ArrayList<String>();
```

For that matter even this will compile & run:

```
List a = new ArrayList<Date>();
a.add(new Integer(5));
```

**Also a note about `generics` and `type erasure` here:**

Generics are implemented by Java compiler as a front-end conversion called erasure. 
Type erasure applies to the use of generics. When generics are used, they're converted into compile time checks and run time type casts.

Due to type erasure mechanism this code:

```
List<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
a.add("foo");
String x = a.get(0);
```

gets compiled into:

```
List a = new ArrayList();
a.add("foo");
String x = (String) a.get(0);
```

---

Similarly your code:

```
List a = new ArrayList<String>();
a.add(new Integer(5));
```

gets compiled into this (**due to type erasure**):

```
List a = new ArrayList();
a.add(new Integer(5));
```

Thus no compilation or run time error is generated.

**However you will note the difference when you try to do get item from the list:**

```
int i = a.get(0); // compilation error due to type mismatch
```

Which is due to the fact that your list is declared as raw type. To avoid this error you need to either use generics to declare your list OR else do a type cast like above. i.e.

Either use generic type in your list:

```
List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
a.add(new Integer(5));    
int i = a.get(0);
```

Or else do this casting: (**not recommended**)

```
List a=new ArrayList<Date>();
a.add(new Integer(5));
int i = (Integer) a.get(0);
```

**PS:** Note that at run time there's no way of finding out that particular type e.g. String was used for declaring your list object.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify a generic type in the actual definition

if you wrote

```
List<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
a.add(new Integer(5));
```

will not compile.

Comment: I know it, thanks. I am wondering why it's running without any exceptions

Comment: Its running without exceptions because ArrayList uses an Object[] under the hood to store data, and Integer is a subclass of Object

Answer (score 1):

You should do

```
List<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
a.add(new Integer(5));
```

- List means that compiler will check whether only `String` objects are being added into the collection.

> Can anybody explain this?

This is possible because

- There is no type safety at runtime because of type erasuse
- The statement `List a`  means there is no compile time check what objects are being added into the list.

As of java 7 you do not have to write `List<String> a = new ArrayList<String>()` for type safety. You can simply use the diamond operator and achieve the same using `List<String> a = new ArrayList();`

Answer (score 1):

`List a` is a raw type which is devoid of generics. This is the exact same reason why you are able to add Integers to it.

To enforce the correct behaviour change the List to use generics.

```
List<String> a
```

Answer (score 1):

Generic data is erased after compilation. That means

```
List<String> a=new ArrayList<String>();
```

will be changed to what you see below, in the class file

```
List a=new ArrayList();
```

Now to answer your question, the type of `a` is `List`, which is **raw List** and you can **add anything** to it. Generics are present to put **compile time restrictions**. That means say you had

```
List<String> a=new ArrayList<String>();
```

this line will generate compile time error

```
a.add(new Integer(1)); //error
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the older legacy code was allowed to put anything at all (except
primitives) into a collection. And in order to support legacy code, Java 5 and Java 6
allows your newer type safe code to make use of older code.

So, the Java 5 or Java 6 compiler is forced into letting you compile your new type
safe code even though your code invokes a method of an older class that takes a
non-type safe argument and does who knows what with it.

In fact the compiler will warn you.The compiler generated a perfectly valid class file from the compilation, but it was kind enough to tell you by saying, in so many words, "I seriously hope you know what you are doing because this old code has NO respect (or even knowledge) of your `<String>` typing, and can do whatever the heck it wants to your precious `ArrayList<String>` ."